# PHP status page works but Nginx logs error

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I've managed to enable php status page inside docker container with following Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen      *:80;

    location /php-status {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

So when I'm trying to curl /php-status I get valid response with full status information.

But there is a problem: Nginx keep loggin error :

> *1 realpath() "/etc/nginx/html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.8, server: , request: "GET /php-status HTTP/1.1"

Indeed there is no `/etc/nginx/html` directory inside the container.

I've tried to create `/etc/nginx/html` but in this case I receive `File not found` response from status page.

Any suggestions how to keep php status page working without any nginx errors?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Also here are some of `fastcgi_params`:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
```

Comment: can you try and allow connections from 0.0.0.0 instead of only 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Mihai, result is the same: valid response and error in Nginx error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!

1. Just like [EternalHour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327810/6447334) posted, I had to set existing `root` directory.
2. But also I had non-default `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME` setting.

Here is the result config:

```
server {
    listen      *:80;

    location /php-status {
        root /;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/nginx/html` is the default document root. It's looking for that because based on what you've provided, you haven't specified anything else with the `root` directive.

Maybe try this depending where the document root is.

```
server {
    listen      *:80;

    location /php-status {
        root /;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Result is `File not found.` if root is specified. And I've added some `fastcgi_params` in description, maybe it will help